# Why am I getting InvalidCastException passing a string to a VariantType parameter?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, .net

I have:

```
Protected Sub SepInsert(ByVal mriId As VariantType, 
                        ByVal aeId As VariantType, 
                        ByVal absId As VariantType)
...
End Sub
```

and want to call it with a DropDownList selection like this:

```
Protected Sub cmdNewPrelinkedMri_Click(ByVal sender As Object, 
                                       ByVal e As System.EventArgs
                                      ) Handles cmdNewPrelinkedMri.Click
    SepInsert(ddlMriUnassigned.SelectedValue, -1, -1)
End Sub
```

where the ddl selected value is, of course, a string (e.g., "0412B0").

I am getting an InvalidCastException saying: Conversion from string "0412B0" to type 'Integer' is not valid. Why does it want to convert to 'Integer' when the parameter is declared as VariantType?

What am I misunderstanding or doing wrong? Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Thanks Sky. As for your PS, I'm with you -- I'm sure the fact that I've never used VariantType before is why the behavior is tripping me up. I'm quite surprised that the type-checking is looking inside of SepInsert to see how mriId will be used... I'd have thought it would be satisfied at the parameter declaration level and left SepInsert to do what it likes with its variant values...

Here's the reference to mriId in SepInsert:
    sql &= ", '" & mriId & "'"

Looks like a string to me... why the 'Integer' complaint?

There are reasons why I was trying VariantType but I may reconsider...

Comment: oh... I guess actually it looks like an undefined usage to me... it must be defaulting to int

Comment: Hey, this might interest you... http://skysanders.net/code/mapObjex/mapMarker.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some statement in SepInsert is trying to force mriId into an int. Show the whole code if you can't find it.

Comment: PS: You should try to avoid variants when at all possible. If you know it is a string type it as a string. just sayin....